How can I replace a Value of a variable with value that a user inputs on MDTextField
I assigned a value but i want it to be changing every time a user input something.Like
Initially
number = "054343232"

then
number = MDTextField(text = "Enter a number")
print(number)

So I want the program to be abandoning the Value it had at the beginning (054343232) and take on the new value (What a user write)
Honestly, I dont know how to go about it. This is my second week since i started learning python and kivymd
for whats worthy it . I tried
number = number = MDTextField(text = "Enter a number")


This is correct.
number = MDTextField(text = "Enter a number")

Then to get its current content,
print(number.text)

However, since it's a GUI, you'd print during some action, like a button click or focus change away from the input field. Otherwise, you'll end up always printing Enter a number after the creation of the field, and no chance to type in it
